# Asp.net core equivalent of Type.IsAssignableFrom

Tags: asp.net-core

Previously I was able to check if a type is assignable from an other. I need this in a generic base class.

```
this.GetType().IsAssaignableFrom(otherObject.GetType())
```

How can I achieve the same in asp.net core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check here : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/ . Specifically the section on "Reflection".

To quote :

> C# var members = obj.GetType().GetMembers();
>
> becomes
>
> C# using System.Reflection; ... var members =
>   obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetMembers();

Apparently they are bringing it back in future versions of .net core. You can see on the page it links to this non-existent page on Github : https://github.com/dotnet/apireviews/tree/master/2016-01-19-reflection which apparently described a bunch of changes to the reflection namespace.

Comment: Thank you, that was it !!! System.Reflection.TypeInfo provides the method .IsAssaignableFrom and I can obtain it trough GetTypeInfo extion method.

Answer (score 1):

> With the advent of .NET Native, we have a technology that allows us to statically link your application with the framework and third party dependencies. For the linking to be viable, it’s important that it can identify the parts of the framework that you’re not using. In other technologies, such as C++, this is somewhat straightforward as these systems don’t have dynamisms such as reflection. Of course, .NET Native still supports reflection but we wanted to make the platform more pay-for-play friendly, meaning that you don’t have to pay for features that you don’t use. This is especially true for reflection, as it imposes significant constraints on what the runtime and compilers can do based on static information.
>
> So ideally, reflection should be an optional component in .NET Core that you might decide not to use in your application at all. The tricky part is that System.Object has a dependency on reflection via Object.GetType(). In order to break that dependency, we decided that System.Type no longer represents the full-blown reflection type information but only the type name. This means that System.Type in .NET Core no longer contains APIs such as GetMembers(), but continues to expose APIs such as Name.
>
> In order to get access to the additional type information you have to invoke an extension method called GetTypeInfo() that lives in System.Reflection. It returns the new type TypeInfo which is what Type used to be. In other words, a line of code like this:
>
> C#
>   var members = obj.GetType().GetMembers();
>
> becomes
>
> C#
>   using System.Reflection;
>   ...
>   var members = obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetMembers();

[.Met Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/)